# McEliece key size

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, mceliece

There's a lot of references about McEliece key size being the barrier for proper usage of the algorithm, exactly (or roughly) how large are the keys?

Comment: The *public* keys are upwards of 1MiB these days, though there are at least 1 or 2 [techniques](https://cardis2020.its.uni-luebeck.de/files/CARDIS2020_Roth_ClassicMcElieceImplementation_paper.pdf) to ease this burden on embedded devices.

Answer (score 4):

As you probably know the public key in McEliece is an $k \times n $ binary matrix, encoding a generator matrix for a randomly permuted Goppa code (i.e. $G_{\mathsf{pub}} = SGP$, where $S$ is any $k \times k$ invertible binary matrix, $G$ a $k \times n$ generator matrix for an $(n, k, t)$ binary Goppa code, and $P$ a $n \times n$ permutation matrix).

McEliece originally proposed the use of a (1024,524,101) binary Goppa code. That would translate to a public key size of roughly 32kB (calculated as: $(n-k) \times k / (8 * 2^{10})$). However, later cryptanalysis have made this choice of parameters obsolete. More up-to-date parameter sets can be found [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/271.pdf) (Table 2). Drawing a few values from that table we have:

- For an expected security level of $2^{80}$ using a (1702,1219,91) code: 72kB;
- For an expected security level of $2^{96}$ using a (2440,1877,101) code: 129kB;
- For an expected security level of $2^{109}$ using a (2804,2048,133) code: 189kB.

Answer (score 2):

McEliece public keys need about 100 kByte to 1 MByte depending on the desired security level.

- 65 kB for 80 bits of security (too low, corresponds to 1024 bit RSA)
- 150 kB for 112 bits of security
- 220 kB for 128 bits of security
- 1000 kB for 256 bits of security

The [McBits paper](http://binary.cr.yp.to/mcbits.html) contains the following table:

[image: Table from McBits paper]